# Linear Regression in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, linear-regression, scatter-plot

first of all my data:

```
dput(df_TB_d[1:10,])

structure(list(Name = c("Baden-Württemberg", "Bayern", "Berlin",
"Brandenburg", "Bremen", "Hamburg", "Hessen", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern",
"Niedersachsen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen"), Land = c("BW", "BY",
"BE", "BB", "HB", "HH", "HE", "MV", "NI", "NW"), Studierende = c(331424,
348590, 142923, 50800, 32522, 72500, 211539, 39738, 183916, 643135
), Bevoelkerung = c(10879618, 12843514, 3520031, 2484826, 671489,
1787408, 6176172, 1612362, 7926599, 17865516), Grundmittel = c(3065086400,
3145532700, 1370039300, 285097600, 216487680, 605016000, 2054458300,
463440300, 2051042000, 6165363300), Ausg_stud = c(9248.23307907695,
9023.58845635273, 9585.85602037461, 5612.15748031496, 6656.65334235287,
8345.04827586207, 9711.95996955644, 11662.3961950778, 11152.0585484678,
9586.42166885646)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to plot a graph which looks like this:
https://www.learnbyexample.org/r-scatter-plot-base-graph/

With the “Bevoelkerung” on the x-axis and “Studierende” on the y-axis.

I work with ggplot2 because I need the typical grey background.

My command so far:

```
ggplot()+
 geom_point(data=df_TB_d,
            mapping = aes(x=Bevoelkerung, y=Studierende))
```

My problem: I can’t to the linear regression. Of course, I searched for the command but whenever I did it (and I tried many ways), I get the error:

```
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Can someone please tell me, where I did my mistake?

And: I need the dots to transform into the federal states’ abbreviation, e.g., the dot which represents Berlin is no longer a dot but a “BE”, for Berlin.

Thank you so much for your time & Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `geom_smooth` for the regression line and `geom_text` for the labels.

```
ggplot(df_TB_d, aes(x=Bevoelkerung, y=Studierende)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Land)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. Works perfectly. Two question: What does the "se=FALLSE" mean? And with the command "geom_text" we ensure that the names are beside the dots, right?

Comment: 1. Try removing `, se = FALSE` and see what happens. 2. Right.

Comment: Oh, okay. You removed the confidence bands. All right. Thank you.